# ruby on rails: before_validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in domainpost.rb i have this:

```
class Domainpost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content,  :additiona, :registerdate, :expiredate, :registerin, :price 

  belongs_to :user
  before_save { |domainpost| domainpost.content = content.downcase }

  before_validation :pricecheck

  validates :price, allow_blank: false, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'domainposts.created_at DESC'

  def pricecheck
    if  price.blank?
    price = 'no price'
  end
end
```

and it isnt work
when price in post is blank after save is stil blank,
any idea what i do wrong?

Comment: Maybe your price has numerical format, therefore string cannot be saved there?

Comment: @user2531122 is a local variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because instead of setting attribute `price` of `Domainpost` instance, you set a local variable. Instead you should do:

```
def pricecheck
  self.price = 'no price' if price.blank?
end
```

Comment: No need to explicitly put "self", as price = 'no price' and self.price = 'no price' is equal in this case. While inside pricecheck method, self points to the object being created/updated, so self is not needed.

Comment: You are wrong. When you use setter methods, it's necessary to explicitly point the receiver of message. Otherwise, only local variable will be set. Look at the example:
`price = 'no price'`
`price # => 'no price'`
`self.price # => nil`.

Answer (score 1):

As answer by @Merek Lipka and @muttonlamb you can try those approach but I suggest is defined a `default value` on your database side

like on your migration for price field simply do this

```
t.[price_data_type],:price,:default => "Your Default value"
```

Well this will take care of your check in model I believe